# How to execute batch file many times until required file is exist, then stop the batch file

Tags: batch-file

Below is my code.

```
pushd \\172.31.100.101\dir1\dir2\
set xxx=%CD%\dir3\dir4
set yyy=%CD%\dir5\dir6\r2.txt

IF EXIST %yyy% (
    echo R2 aldy completed > c:\r2.txt
    exit
)

set "filenames="
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    forfiles /p %xxx% /m Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx /s /d +0 /C "cmd /C echo/ @path"
') do (
    call set "filenames=%%filenames%% %%F"
)

IF NOT EXIST %filenames% (
    echo Failed_Match_Data is missing > c:\Failure1.txt
    exit
)
    echo %filenames% is exist > c:\Success1.txt

timeout /t 30 /nobreak
"C:\windows\notepad.exe"
echo R2 started > %yyy%

popd
```

I'll schedule this batch file at 8am daily with interval execution every 15mins until 11 a.m., then stop. I don't know when `Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx` will be ready in the required folder between 8am until 11am. My objective is that once the file is ready, the next execution will skip the task of running notepad.exe. I put a timeout there because I want to ensure that `Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx` is finished writing to the disk before running notepad.exe. The xlsx is quite small, about 20kb in size. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have obviously done some research on this problem.

`c:\r2.txt` needs to be deleted daily, otherwise on the first execution of this procedure, yesterday's `c:\r2.txt` will already exist and you'll exit.

Your next step is to accumulate a list of `Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx` files in `filenames`. This indicates that you are aware that there may be 0, 1 or more than 1 of these files.

The statement

```
IF NOT EXIST %filenames% (
```

will therefore be resolved to one of

```
IF NOT EXIST (

IF NOT EXIST filename1 (

IF NOT EXIST filename1 filename2 (
```

The first will attempt to find a file named `(` and would yield a syntax error since you have provided no "what to do if `(` does not exist" action.

The second test would always fail since we know filename1 exists - we gather its name in the previous step.

The third test would always fail for the same reason, but the instruction would be to execute filename2 if filename1 has disappeared.

Possibly your test should have been

```
if not defined filenames (
```

which would test whether `filenames` is set to a list of the files that were found or was "set" to *nothing* as no filenames were found.

So - to solve your apparent problem (and this is untested)

```
pushd \\172.31.100.101\dir1\dir2\
set xxx=%CD%\dir3\dir4
set yyy=%CD%\dir5\dir6\r2.txt

DEL c:\r2.txt >nul 2>nul

:again

IF EXIST %yyy% (
    echo R2 aldy completed > c:\r2.txt
    exit
)

dir /s /a-d "%xxx%\Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
 (
  echo Failed Match Data files at %time% on %date%
  dir /b /a-d "%xxx%\Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx"
 )> c:\Success1.txt
 start "Failed Match Data" notepad c:\success1.txt
 exit
)
rem no Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx
if "%time:~0,2%" neq "11" (
 timeout /t 900 /nobreak >nul
 goto again
)

(
 echo No Failed Match Data files at %time% on %date%
 dir /b /a-d "%xxx%\Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx"
)> c:\Failure1.txt
start "Failed Match Data" notepad c:\Failure1.txt
exit
```

You need to figure out whether `r2.txt` is `c:\r2.txt` or `%yyy%`

This procedure is designed to be scheduled to start at 08:00, and needs no repeats.

first delete `r2.txt` (8am only) - the `>nul 2>nul` suppresses messages

Then see whether `r2.txt` exists - exit if true

Then see whether any of the `failed` files exist.
If so, write out the `success` file, start notepad and exit
If not, see whether the time is `11...` by comparing the first 2 characters of `%time%` to `11` If not, then timeout for 900 seconds and repeat the process.

Otherwise, it's 11:00 so write out the `failure` file, start notepad and exit

Note that the syntax

```
(
 echo ....
 dir....
)>filename
```

redirects the `echo` and `dir` output to the file to build a report

And

```
start "quotedstring" notepad filename
```

opens filename in notepad and assigns quotedstring as the window title. Quotedstring may be empty, but the quotes must be included (actually, not relevant in this case, but a good habit to adopt)

Comment: I can't use `if exist "%xxx%\Failed_Match_Data*.xlsx"` due to there are few folders under dir4. That's the reason why I'm using `forfiles /s @path`.

Also, should I insert `popd` before every `exit` cmd ?

Comment: The `dir /s ...` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if no matching files are found on the tree, `1` otherwise. `exit` will terminate the batch process, so no `popd` is required.